# Limiting RAM usage during performance tests

Tags: io, linux-kernel, memory-management, swap

I have to run some performance tests, to see how my programs work when the system runs out of RAM and the system starts thrashing. Ideally, I would be able to change the amount of RAM used by the system.

I haved tried to by boot my system (running Ubuntu 10.10) in single user mode with a limited amount of physical memory, but with the parameters I used (max_addr=300M, max_addr=314572800 or mem=300M) the system did not use my swap partition.

Is there a way to limit the amount of RAM used by the total system, while still using swap space?

The point is to measure the total running time of each program as a function of the input size. I am not trying to pinpoint performance problems, I am trying to compare algorithms, which means I need accuracy.

Comment: There are tools for this sort of thing, for example [stressapptest](http://code.google.com/p/stressapptest/)

Comment: @David Hefferman: I am trying to test my programs, not my hardware.

Comment: ørgen It will test your apps too.

Comment: I know this is a Linux-Tagged question, however for Windows users, this might be useful: [Edit Hardware Usage via Windows Boot Config](https://helgeklein.com/blog/2018/11/how-to-limit-cpu-ram-via-the-windows-boot-configuration/) - be very careful, breaking the Boot Config can be a pain to resolve (may even need to reinstall Windows in the worst case).

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple c program which

- Will allocate large amount of memory.
- Keep on accessing allocated memory random to try to keep in main memory (in an infinite loop).

Now run this program (one or few processes) so that you allocate enough memory to cause the thrashing of process you are testing.

Comment: I thought about doing something like this, but unfortunately it will not give accurate results. For one thing, it will hog all the memory bandwidth.

Comment: Rather the plainly running loop run it with some time break. May be 20 random access a second. With changing the process to simulate other process do should help you.